# Should I reply to Travel Grant Award Notification?

Tags: conference, funding, travel

Do I reply to travel grant chair for notifying me approval of my travel grant award application for a conference? (Thanking him/her.. etc)

What is my appropriate action? Or is it not really expected and I should just follow instructions of submitting listed receipts to the specified person in email?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best option is to respond very briefly. This is **basic courtesy, to let them know you received the notification and will accept the travel grant**. Of course, it is also wise to remember to submit the receipts as requested! The first is courtesy, the second business.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think it's necessary, but my inclination is to just write a one or two sentence response, just saying "Thanks for the wonderful news.  I'm looking forward to the conference." This way they know you got the email and are still planning on attending.